# Assign "Go to Declaration" to Ctrl + Click

Tags: visual-studio-code

By default `Ctrl + LMB` performs *Go to Definition*.

Is it possible to change `Ctrl + LMB` to perform *Go to Declaration* instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can change keyboard shortcuts by clicking File -> Preferences -> Keyboard shortcuts. Here you are able to search and add your key binding.

Comment: You can't add the keybind `Ctrl + LMB`, which is what I'm looking for.